# Android Studio doesn't see the FloatingActionButton hide()/show() methods

Tags: android, android-studio, floating-action-button

I'm trying to create, then hide, a `FloatingActionButton`:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.hide(); //This method should hide it, right?
```

I can see that there's a `hide()` method [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#hide()), but when I try to call the method in Android Studio, it doesn't seem to see the `hide` and `show` methods at all!

Does the method not actually exist?  Does it exist and Android Studio isn't working? What's going on?

Comment: Probably just need to update the support design library version.

Comment: How do I do that? (Sorry, I'm a complete and total Android n00b)

Comment: Use the sdk manager to update, then modify the build.gradle accordingly

Comment: It worked! Yay!  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out I just had to update the support design library; I was using an older version. (Thanks @Daniel Nugent!)